# Three-column HTML template for PHP site

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to make a HTML three-column template, [using a layout from html.am](http://www.html.am/templates/downloads/view-source.cfm?template=layout-templates/3-column-layout.cfm). I've used the layout as a sandbox for experimenting with CSS and design, now I want to start from scratch without having to rely on a template someone else has designed.

This is for a PHP/MySQL site using Twig as the template engine. The content is extracted from the database - it's an information site which looks magazine-like in design (since that's the look I'm aiming for) which is updated every now and then (not often), yet it doesn't need a full blog features like commenting, uploads etc. as it's a fansite / information site rather than a full-blown WordPress-style website that has a large amount of followers and heavy social media presence.

[This page here](http://www.autocarindia.com/auto-reviews/ford-fiesta-facelift-review-test-drive-388177,0.aspx) is the one I'm influenced by currently.

I could just save the page from my Firefox browser and then edit it by hand in a text editor, but I'm trying to create my own basic design.

Using View Source on Firefox, I notice the page I linked to above [the second link] is made up of DIVs as in the first example.

What I am trying to do is emulate the effect where there is a lot of space between the divs before you get to the text saying FIRST DRIVE (a DIV according to view source on Firefox), as you can see on the page.

I would appreciate any advice on how to get this right with CSS/HTML so that the page isn't based around using others' templates which I have modified - recently I haven't done that much with actual HTML/CSS for templating.

Edit:

My current code for the existing page design (as pure HTML, which I want to replace from scratch, using modified html.am coding):

```html
   <body>  
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
    <style>
   body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
   }
   
   #header {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
   }
   
   #header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
   }
   
   main {
    padding-bottom: 10010px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
   }
   
   #nav {
    padding-bottom: 10010px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    margin-left: -100%;
    background: #eee;
   }
   
   #footer {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px 0;
   }
 
   #wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
   }
      
   #content {
    margin-left: 230px; /* Same as 'nav' width */
   }
   
   .innertube {
    margin: 15px; /* Padding for content */
    margin-top: 0;
   }
  
   p {
    color: #555;
   }
 
   nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   }
   
   nav ul a {
    color: darkgreen;
    text-decoration: none;
   }
   
   #container {
   width: 500px;
}

#container img {
height: 399px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
  
    </style>
    </head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>2 Column Layout &mdash; Left Menu with Header &amp; Footer</title>
      <header id="header">
       <div class="innertube">
        <h1>Header...</h1>
       </div>
      </header>
      
      <div id="wrapper">
      
       <main>
        <div id="content">
         <div class="innertube">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
          <p></p>
         </div>
        </div>
       </main>
       
       <nav id="nav">
        <div class="innertube">
         <h3>Left heading</h3>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         </ul>
         <h3>Left heading</h3>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         </ul>
         <h3>Left heading</h3>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </nav>
      
      </div>
      
      <footer id="footer">
       <div class="innertube">
        <p>Footer...</p>
       </div>
      </footer>
     
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: show us what you've tried and done so far with some code samples. Also, this has nothing to do with php.

Answer (score 0):

Put `#nav_right` after `#nav` in page and give it a `width` something like `200px`. Then give a `margin-right: 200px` to `#content`.